# configuring a custom domain name for an azure vm and godaddy

Tags: azure, nginx, dns, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

Recently I have started to configure my VM at azure I deployed 4 projects with nginx but I have a problem to configure my VM with godaddy. To configure a domain name in Godaddy, I need to set minimum 2 DNS address, but my VM has only one DNS address. Can someone show me how to allow more than one DNS address in my VM or at least how to bypass this issue and make my VM work fine with Godaddy.