# How to associate a domain with an Azure VM

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

We just put a website on an Azure VM and can access it with an IP address no problem.
We also  have a domain on 1and1 and have set it to point to the VM IP and this works.... However the address in the address bar is the IP address and not the domain.

How do  I get the domain to  display.?

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow: not programming-related. Also, this is already documented. A simple search for `"azure vm custom domain name"` should take you right to it.

Comment: Nope not documented. Two of us have been searching for 8 hours now.

Comment: The domain name from Azure or third party?

Comment: From third party.

Comment: You may refer, "[Configuring a custom domain for an Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449401/configuring-a-custom-domain-name-for-an-azure-vm-and-godaddy/45453110#45453110)".

Answer (score 0):

> However the address in the address bar is the IP address and not the
>   domain.

**It is a by design behavior**, we can't find third party domain name in Azure portal.

In Azure, **only** Azure domain name can show in Azure portal. Also we can't find the domain name in that VM.

Only that VM join to one domain, we can find the domain name in that IP address bar.

By the way, we can't use public IP address to find the domain name.

Hope this helps:)