# Azure VM - linking the *.cloudapp.azure.com URL to godaddy?

Tags: azure, ssl

I am trying to figure out how to link my *.cloudapp.azure.com VM's DNS info to a GoDaddy subdomain off my company's site. I am not able to wrap my head around the directions on Azure.

The second part is we have a purchased wildcard SSL cert for our main domain on GoDaddy that we need to install. I can see you can purchase certs from Azure, however we have our own.

Thanks for any assistance anyone can provide in this matter.

Comment: Please move your post to another relevant SE community.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CNames to link Azure domains to your existing domain. Just créate a CName that point to your Azure DNS Name. Example:

you need vm.company.com to point to your vm called myvm in Azure.
créate CNAME vm that point to myvm.location.cloudapp.azure.com

As for the cert, copy it to the vm and import like you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS zone is used to host the DNS records for a particular domain. To start hosting your domain in Azure DNS, you need to create a DNS zone for that domain name. Each DNS record for your domain is then created inside this DNS zone. Finally, to publish your DNS zone to the Internet, you need to configure the name servers for the domain.

Each of these steps is described in the following steps:

**Step1:** First create the Azure Virtual Machines.

**Step2:** To get DNS addresses, you need create DNS zones with your domain name.

Go to Azure Portal => New => search DNS zones => Create DNS zones

Name= azurewala.com, Subscription, Resource Group, and Location

[image]

**Step3:** Once Azure DNS zones created you can see four Name Servers.

[image]

**Step4:** Go to GoDaddy control panel and click on the DNS.

[image]

**Step5:** Change the Nameservers by choose your new nameserver type as: Custom

Note: Copy and paste the Name Servers from Azure DNS to GoDaddy

And make sure you have to remove the extra dot before you save.

[image]

**Step6:** Open Created DNS Zones and add a record set

Name: www
Type: A
TTL: 1 Hours

IP ADDRESS: 52.176.102.178

Note: Give IP Address of the VM.

[image]

You may refer detailed workaround steps here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449401/configuring-a-c‌​ustom-domain-name-fo‌​r-an-azure-vm-and-go‌​daddy/45453110#45453‌​110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45449401/configuring-a-c%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bustom-domain-name-fo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Br-an-azure-vm-and-go%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdaddy/45453110#45453%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B110)

Comment: This works well for a domain name, but what about a sub domain? I can't seem to find any resources to make this happen. Would we need a separate domain name? Ideally this would need to be under our company main domain name.